# Where do we put the question mark in a long question/statement?

Tags: punctuation, question-mark

Without the question mark, it is simple...

> Can we make it in one hour — as I want to eat my dinner now.

(I like the dash as a clear separator for the question and statement parts of the sentence)

Adding a question mark, it looks wrong to me in all permutations. What should I be doing with this?

> Can we make it in one hour as I want to eat my dinner now?
>      Can we make it in one hour? as I want to eat my dinner now.
>      Can we make it in one hour — as I want to eat my dinner now?
>      Can we make it in one hour? — as I want to eat my dinner now.

Comment: The easiest remedy would be: _Can we make it in one hour? I want to eat my dinner now._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This statement would obviously occur only in a non-formal context or as a direct quotation in a formal context. In either case, no formal ‘rule’ applies.

Instead, placement of the question mark should be guided by the actual phonetic contour of the utterance. There will almost certainly be an elevated tone on ‘hour’, which would call for a question mark. There may also be an elevated pitch on ‘dinner now’, if the speaker is requesting rather than demanding time to eat; if so, this would call for a second question mark.

In either case, I would use the dash. It sets off the second clause without detaching it, as  capitalizing ‘As’ would.

So either of these:

> Can we make it in one hour? — as I want to eat my dinner now.
>   Can we make it in one hour? — as I want to eat my dinner now?

Comment: Second question mark - are you mad :-?

Comment: @BillyMoon  Think of it as "Can we postpone? --so I can eat? --please?"  There's not just one reading.

Comment: @StoneyB: FWIW, I like the dual question marks with "so I can eat my dinner now?" but not so much with "as I want to eat my dinner now?" The "as I want" just seems too declaritive, no matter now I try to read it.

Comment: @J.R.  I agree; but we weren't invited to rewrite it, so I just treat it as a given quote. Me personally, I'd say "'cause I need" or as you say "so I can". But I don't use "as" much anyway.

Comment: @StoneyB Yeah, I don't want it re-written, but re-dressed only. I am trying to formulate an opinion on a general rule for this kind of stuff, where the words should not be changed, but the formatting  should reveal the meaning that is clear when spoken. I think I agree with the hyphens being retained for the reasons you state. I still find the dual question marks freak me out a bit.

Comment: `Can we make it in one hour(?) — as I want to eat my dinner now.` looks crazy, but is closer to the intention.

Comment: `Can we make it in one hour..? as I want to eat my dinner now.` or something like this?

Comment: Make the whole sentence a question: _Can we make it in one hour so (that) I can eat my dinner now?_ Using "as" to mean "because" is anathema to me. "Re-dressing" is very much like putting on fresh lipstick. Or make it a Q & a statement: _Can we make it in one hour? I'd like to eat my dinner now._ The 3rd option's "Don't care about the punctuation: it doesn't matter". It's all personal opinion anyway: "...the formatting should reveal the meaning that is clear when spoken." Traditional punctuation is clear. Idiosyncratic punctuation's usually murky vanity.

Comment: @BillyMoon  You're freaked because you wrote it, or heard it, and know what it's supposed to sound like. I look at the unpunctuated sentence as an actor would, asking What are the possible readings here? --*then* I go back as writer and punctuate it to reflect the two different readings I discern. Histrionic Corollary to the Fundamental Law: If you leave the actor a choice he will take the wrong one.