# Where Does the Question Mark Go When Listing the Options to Choose From?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

For example, I'm trying to ask someones opinion on what to choose when there are two alternatives. Like, "Which one is better, selling it or keeping it?", but I'm not sure if this is the correct way to punctuate this sentence. Couple ways I can think of are:

1. Which one is better, selling it or keeping it?
2. Which one is better; selling it or keeping it?
3. Which one is better? Selling it or keeping it?

I'd normally go with the first one but it looked weird when I formed a sentence like this "When there is a problem with your car, what is better, selling it or repairing it?"

I know I can form the sentence in a different way, such as "Is selling your car better than repairing it when there is something wrong with it?", so that I need to use less punctuation. However, I want to learn how to form this since I hear it a lot in daily life. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Use a colon or dash.

Comment: Similar questions: [one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91819/where-do-we-put-the-question-mark-in-a-long-question-statement)  ///  [two](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103807/how-to-use-the-question-mark-in-multiple-choice-questions)

Comment: No [punctuation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/IELL-Punctuation.pdf) mark exists that captures that particular chunk of intonation and rhythm. So do the best you can with the limited tools at our disposal.

Comment: This not an answer but, interestingly, it is argued in https://www.scribendi.com/academy/articles/question_mark.en.html that "You might be surprised to know that the question mark, while used exclusively to ask questions, can function in some rather unique situations, the most surprising being its ability to stand in for a comma. Take this sentence, for example: "Where is Eric's car? and where is he, for that matter?" asked Sarah."